# ROS Answers SE migration: gazebo groovy

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what are the specification to run gazeb groovy, 'cause on my computer with intel I5 , 4 gb ram , gforce 512. and it's so slowly!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54501/gazebo-groovy/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run gazebo 1 and 1.4 on a Core2Duo which is much slower than your processor. It works reasonably well. What kind of simulation are you running? And is your video card being used or the one on the processor?

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-07**:
well i need to work with shadow hand, but in fact when i just spawn gazebo empty_world, it's extremley slowly just to turn around the world. wis using the video card.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-02-07**:
Check the drivers from your video card and make sure the external card is used, not the one on the processor. empty_world only should be running smooth.